# Allow a user to flag the same node/user multiple times

Tags: flags

The flag module allows flags to be defined per user.  For example, User 1 can flag Node A and B, and User 2 can flag Node A but not Node B.

In this situation, a flag is either on or off per user.  However, is there a way to allow a single user to flag the same piece of content multiple times?

Use case: I have created two content types, **Message** and **Reply**.  I want to limit the number of times that users can reply to a message (say, to 3).  To do this, I was going to use Rules to automatically flag the original *message* each time a user writes a *reply*.  However, since content is either flagged or unflagged, I don't see any way to allow a user to flag the content multiple times.

Any ideas on how to approach this use case are welcome, including using modules other than the flag module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [Five Star](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module and incrementing the rating each time?  Eg, first reply, rate the message 1.  Next reply, re-rate the message 2.  When you get to 3 (or 4 or 5) don't allow more. You could implement this directly with the [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) if you wanted to, too, I'd imagine, if you needed higher than 5.

Comment: I see in another question you are having potential issues with this.  Could using the node reference count module help out in a different solution?  http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_count for more info.